# How can I get a plot to display coordinates when the mouse cursor is on the curve?

Tags: plotting

If i do a plot i get a bunch of values, but only vaguely can you see what value each plot has. How do i do a mouseover to see the coordinates? In a pie chart it just tells you the value when you mouseover automatically but iv not seen that happen in any other. why?

ps, your quality check is really annoying since it demands me to say stuff like what iv already tried (which i managed to solve by saying this), even if im just asking a question.

Comment: [How to | Get Coordinates for Points in a Plot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GetCoordinatesForPointsInAPlot.html)

Comment: thx for the downvote, not toxic at all. also thats not what im looing for, as it shows the mouse location not the plots location.

Comment: Downvote was from me. The question is poorly formulated and totally lacks any effort from your side.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I did google exactly your title, appending *Mathematica* (i.e "How to see cords of a plot mathematica"), and the link supplied by @JasonB. was the first hit. Then I googled "How to see cords of a plot mathematica stack exchange", and a host of pages came up about getting coordinates from a plot.  I never use the search functionality within stack exchange; I always use google.

Comment: well none of them are what im looking for as they complicate things with sliders and what not, i just want it to be mouseover like on the pie chart. There is a function called mouseover but its application is vague. in a pie chart it just says the number of that slice like "35" for example, in a plot it should then say its value, "x, y" when i mouseover the plotted value.

Comment: Did you go to the link provided by @JasonB.? That is *exactly* what that link shows you how to do.

Comment: @TeKett - You come into this post with a chip on your shoulder, complaining about the site in the text of your question.  By saying what you need more explicitly, we can give better help.  It sounds like you want to do a `ListPlot`, and show the x, y coordinates as `Tooltip`s when you hover over the points.  Try this: `ListPlot[Tooltip[#, #] & /@ RandomReal[1, {20, 2}]]`

Comment: @JasonB. - This can be simplified to `ListPlot[Tooltip /@ RandomReal[1, {20, 2}]]` or even  `ListPlot[Tooltip @ RandomReal[1, {20, 2}]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon - thanks, I missed the point "`Tooltip[expr]` is equivalent to `Tooltip[expr,expr]`", I can't find any documentation of `Tooltip[_List]` being expanded to `Tooltip /@ _List`, but a little syntactic sugar never hurt anyone :-)

Comment: all that link explains is how to add dots and to show their cords, not show the cord of a existing plot, as in ListPlot[{{5,10}}], if i do the "get cordinates" it wont give me the plots coordinate, but rather the coordinate of the mouse location, aka pixel. http://prntscr.com/gqujgm

Answer (score 4):

Here is a barebones function that can be applied to a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object to create a mouseover tooltip for plotted lines:

```
addMouseover[g_Graphics] := Module[{lines, pts},
    lines = Cases[Normal[g][[1]], _Line, Infinity];
    If[lines==={}, Return[g]];
    pts = Catenate @ lines[[All,1]];
    With[{nf = Nearest[pts]},
        Show[
            g,
            Epilog -> Dynamic @ DynamicModule[
                {
                pt = nf[MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, {0,0}]],
                scaled = MousePosition[{"GraphicsScaled", Graphics}, None]
                },

                If[scaled===None,
                    {},
                    {
                        Text[
                            Framed[
                                Row[pt[[1]], ","],
                                Background->White,
                                RoundingRadius->5
                            ],
                            pt[[1]],
                            {1.2 Sign[scaled[[1]]-.5], 0}
                        ],
                        AbsolutePointSize[7], Point[pt],
                        White, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pt]
                    }
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Here is an example:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
addMouseover @ plot
```

[image]

If you want to add tooltips for points instead, use:

```
addMouseover[g_Graphics] := Module[{points, pts},
    points = Cases[Normal[g][[1]], _Point, Infinity];
    If[points === {}, Return[g]];
    pts = Partition[Flatten @ points[[All,1]], 2];
    With[{nf = Nearest[pts]},
        Show[
            g,
            Epilog -> Dynamic @ DynamicModule[
                {
                pt = nf[MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, {0,0}]],
                scaled = MousePosition[{"GraphicsScaled", Graphics}, None]
                },

                If[scaled===None,
                    {},
                    {
                        Text[
                            Framed[
                                Row[pt[[1]], ","],
                                Background->White,
                                RoundingRadius->5
                            ],
                            pt[[1]],
                            {1.2 Sign[scaled[[1]]-.5], 0}
                        ],
                        AbsolutePointSize[7], Point[pt],
                        White, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pt]
                    }
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

I like Carl Woll's answer, but just for fun, I'm going to give a simple alternative that involves a little fakery.

For the function I'll use the usual Mathematica poster child, `Sin`

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}];
```

If you just want numbers then you can get them with

```
p2 = 
  ListPlot[Table[Tooltip[{x, Sin[x]}], {x, 0, 2 π, π/100}], 
    PlotStyle -> Transparent];

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image: p2]

But you can get symbolic values at 1° intervals by using the 2nd argument of `Tooltip`, which I think is more interesting way to do what you ask for.

```
p3 = 
  ListPlot[
    Table[Tooltip[{x, Sin[x]}, {N[x/Degree], Sin[x]}], {x, 0, 2 π, π/180}],
    PlotStyle -> Transparent];

Show[p1, p3]
```

[image: p3]